# How to change photo upload size in Dropbox iPad app

Tags: dropbox, ipad

I'm going overseas and will be taking a lot of photos. I'm not taking a laptop, just my iPad mini. I understand that the default setting for photo uploads in the iPad app is *medium*. I can't see any option in setting to increase the default size to *large*.

How can I upload full or large size images?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Files Pro](http://www.olivetoast.com/files/) to upload/download full-resolution images to/from Dropbox.  My need isn't quite the same as yours (I need to do this for accurate graphics when I'm developing apps), but perhaps this might help you.